# React Native - Save project without node_modules folder, and create it later?

Tags: npm, react-native

I've created a react native project with react-native init. Everything is fine, but now I want to save the project to some source control without the large node_modules library (80mb).

So later (when the source is checked out on a different computer for example) when I try to recreate the folder I use **npm install**. 
But now when I run **react-native start** (i am using windows) i get the error:
**"cannot find module '.nodules/es5'"**

The react-native init command did something inside the node_modules that the npm install is not doing. 
What am I missing?

Comment: I just tried this with an app created with RN 0.21.0 and it works:

rm -rf node_modules;
npm install;
react-native start;

What version of RN are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from your description how you have created the project in the first place. I'd recommend using `react-native init projectName` to properly create a project. To run `react-native` you need to first install react native globally- `npm install -g react-native-cli`

If you're using git and github for source control-
`react-native init` command automatically generates a ***.gitignore*** file. Following files are excluded from being added in the source control.

## OSX-

.DS_Store

## Xcode-

build/

*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata
*.xccheckout
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
*.hmap
*.ipa
*.xcuserstate
project.xcworkspace

## Android/IJ

.idea
.gradle
local.properties

## Node.js

node_modules/
npm-debug.log

So even if you run `git add .` (which tracks all the files recursively in the source control) the aforementioned files will not be tracked.

Next time, if you want to generate your project on a different machine, you can simply run

`git clone your_git_repo`

and then

`npm install`.

Comment: @YaronLevi If you're not using your app in production, I'd recommend you to install NVM. Through NVM, you can easily manage your node and npm versions. You can also have multiple node/npm versions simultaneously. That way you'll be testing app on different node/npm versions.